# how to develop firefox addons to use client scanner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox-addon, image-scanner

i have a requirement i want to work with but i dont know from where to start.

Requirement
I want to use the client pc scanner in web browser to scan the image and upload it to the server. 
I have read few web twain addons which uses the native twain to access the scanner and upload the images but none of them are open source.

We have 10 computers which are on intranet and we can allow the web application to use the windows resources through addons

So is there any possible way to develop a firefox addon which uses the com or windows resources to scan the image and send it to the server using the client scanner.
Wrb development platform we are using is asp.net mvc3/4. 
if its possible then can anyone.please guide me how to develop the firefox addon with ease

js-ctypes code / mozilla addon

```
 var libs = ctypes.open('C:\\KPTwainScan.DLL');
      var constructor = libs.declare("Twain", ctypes.winapi_abi,
          ctypes.int32_t,
          ctypes.int32_t,
          ctypes.jschar.ptr,
          ctypes.jschar.ptr,
          ctypes.int32_t);
      var obj = constructor();

      libs.close();
```

C# library Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace @new
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void ShowMessageBox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Alerted");
        }
    }
}
```

no able to invoke the ShowMessageBox Function . Please guide

Comment: For the scanning part this sounds like js-ctypes to me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Standard_OS_Libraries

Comment: can you please guide me a little bit.because i am new to it

Comment: how to call the twain dll to use it in the extension

Comment: Pack the dll with the addon and then with ctypes do `var lib = ctypes.open('PATH TO YOUR DLL');` than you can do `lib.STUFF_IN_YOUR_DLL`

Comment: Reached so far ... I created my own C# library which created a DLL.. I loaded it through the DLL but while declaring it like I am getting error function symbol not found.. can we use C# created DLL ?

Comment: I have reedited the post with the Code @Noitidart

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code of the dll. I'm not sure how to do this, I never did it myself. @nmaier would know for sure.